# How to display signature in SharePoint 2013 mobile version

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, mobile, mobile-view

I am using the following solution to display the a form of a digital signature in SharePoint NewForm of a list. [This is the YouTube video for this solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AZuh72l8eA) and this is [its blog post](http://www.paitgroup.com/easy-digital-signatures-in-sharepoint/). But the problem is that in NewForm in mobile version it is not shown.

Im using the following scrips

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.markrackley.net/scripts/Sketch.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.markrackley.net/scripts/PAITSignature.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.markrackley.net/scripts/PAITSignature.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">`
```

Thanks.